# how to load hive RC format table from a text file

Tags: hive

I have a text file with pipe as delimiter. I want to load the data into a RC formatted hive partition table. I can do that in two steps process. i.e. first loaded into an text format external table and from there I can load into the RC formatted partition table.
But the question is can this be done in one step process using load hadoop command (considering in run time I am not sure about the different partition values).
I have tried below `load data inpath 'hdfs_file_or_directory_path' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE table1 PARTITION (YEAR_DT)` but getting error.
The RC formatted table structure is as below:

```html
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEST.TABLE1(
 Col1 DATE,
 Col2 INT,
 Col3 DOUBLE,
 Col4 VARCHAR(2),
 Col5 VARCHAR(3),
 Col6 SMALLINT,
 Col7 TIMESTAMP
 )
   partitioned by (YEAR_DT INT)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
   STORED AS RCFILE
   LOCATION
   'hdfs_file_or_directory_path'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

The error I am getting is given below:

```html
hive> load data inpath '<hdfs path>'  OVERWRITE INTO TABLE TABLE1 PARTITION(year_dt);
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Invalid partition key & values; keys [year_dt, ], values [])

hive> load data inpath '<hdfs path>'  OVERWRITE INTO TABLE TABLE1 PARTITION(year_dt = 2014);
Loading data to table test.test1 partition (year_dt=2014)
Failed with exception Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
```

Comment: Interesting... I thought "transactional" tables required ORC, a background process for compaction, etc etc  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions

Comment: And why do you define your target table as EXTERNAL since you want to feed it with Hive, which makes it *de facto* a managed table?!

Comment: Anyway, since you don't care to show the error message, there is a very low probability that anyone will investigate. Good luck.

Comment: I have provided the error I am getting in the actual post

Comment: OK. So just begin with something **clean, simple and unambiguous**.  Create an EXTERNAL table STORED AS exactly the format of your input data file, LOCATION = the directory that contains your input data. Then try to SELECT your data; If it 's not 100% OK then drop / re-create until you have a perfect match.

Comment: When you have your EXTERNAL table right, then you can create your target table with whatever Serde, column layout, partitioning, compression that you wish. And you can run an INSERT INTO TABLE trg SELECT x,y,z FROM src_external.

Comment: Yes,  this is exactly the steps I have performed already and that works for me as well. I did mention that in my original post `I can do that in two steps process. i.e. first loaded into an text format table and from there I can load into the RC formatted partition table.`; but I have asked to do it the same in one step, which  I am unable to do so far successfully and that is why posted this question.